# Excel form on a web page

Tags: php, html, excel, web

I'm working on a project a little special and I have to insert an excel form on a web page so that users can fill it online and then on submit it have to be sent by email (as attachment or form) to the recipient of the form. 
The company has no skydrive and the form must be an excel and not an HTML form. 
Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks all !

Comment: You mean like this?  `<a href="excelFile.xls">Click here for the form</a>`  If you just link to the file then users can open it and interact with it.

Comment: No, that's the problem. users have to fill it on the web page like an HTML form.

Comment: After that they have to click for submit it and the form is sent by email as an attachment or other (image, html, etc.)

Comment: Then it kind of needs to *be* an HTML form.  If it needs to be HTML, write it in HTML.  If it needs to be an Excel file, make it an Excel file.  It can't really be both.

Comment: That was my point of view. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the creator of Appizy (http://appizy.com) that aims at converting Excel files into dynamic webapp. If I get it well you could generate your HTML form based on Excel Spreadsheet with Appizy.

Then you "just" need to plug a submit button to the generated webapp to send the data by email.

Answer (score 0):

PHPExcel seems to offer a fully fledged engine for PHP (including calculating ability).

There doesn't seem to be any clear cut examples of how to interact with it via a webpage however.